Parent Widget forces a rebuild on push
I have a search results page (ListView) where the user can navigate to a detailed page through context.pushNamed(...) (from go_router).
class ResultsPage:
  Column of: 
    + Search Bar 
    + Filter Bar 
    + Results List (My ListView)

When I pop back from the DetailPage back to the ResultsPage, I lose the scroll offset.
I tried AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, and manual bookkeeping of the scrollOffset using a scroll controller. But, none worked. I found that the view gets rebuilt when navigating to the new page (which flushes the state of the widgets).
This issue happens in Web (I didn't check somewhere else).

To prevent navigation from losing the current scroll offset, you can hold the current scroll offset before navigating to another screen.
And, when popping back, you can return back to the saved scroll offset.
Gather the idea from the following pseudo code:
class Try extends StatelessWidget{
  
  
  static double? initialOffset;
  
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController(offset: initialOffset??0);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    
    return Scaffold(
    
    body:  ListView.builder(
    scrollController: controller,
    itemBuilder: (context,index){
      
      return ListTile(
      
      onTap: (){
        initialOffset = index * (TileHeight)
      }
      );
    }
    )
    );
  }
}

apply the above idea to your code, this should work even the content get reloaded.
Hope it helps you.
